# WebJob doesn't work when splitting pipeline into build and release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to deploy a WebJob using Azure DevOps. I have the following pipeline:

```
pool:

#  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
  vmImage: windows-2019

  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

variables:
    BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'
    BuildConfiguration: 'release'
    Parameters.solution: '**\*.sln'

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use Net Core 3.1.0'
  inputs:
#    packageType: 'runtime' # Options: runtime, sdk
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.1.100'

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.7.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.7.0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'net build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**\*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'net publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**\*.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebJob\App_Data\jobs\continuous\WJ_Channel_Fetch'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '"dotnet WJ_Channel_Fetch.dll" | Out-File run.cmd -Encoding ASCII; $LASTEXITCODE'
    errorActionPreference: 'stop'
    failOnStderr: false
    ignoreLASTEXITCODE: false
    pwsh: false
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebJob\App_Data\jobs\continuous\WJ_Channel_Fetch'

- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  displayName: 'Stop Azure App Service: XXXX-pipelines2'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Professional (**********)'
    Action: 'Stop Azure App Service'
    WebAppName: 'XXXX-pipelines2'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: XXXX-pipelines2'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Professional (**********)'
    WebAppName: 'XXXX-pipelines2'
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebJob'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true

- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  displayName: 'Start Azure App Service: XXXX-pipelines2'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Professional (**********)'
    Action: 'Start Azure App Service'
    WebAppName: 'XXXX-pipelines2'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

This works perfect, but I want to move the deploy part to a Release pipeline, so I can make use of the approvals between environments (DEV, QA, TEST, PROD).

The problem is that when I move it to a Release pipeline, the WebJob is deployed but it appears to be in an inconsistent state. I can't stop it, nor delete it; the only way to get rid of it is by deleting the WebApp.
If I use only the YAML from above everything works.

This is my Release pipeline:

[image]

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: as Prasun mentioned below this can all be accomplished by using Environments+checks in YAML. Plus there are a bunch of tasks in your YAML which could be removed for better readability... pool>demands are not needed with ms-hosted agent, Usedotnet should be 3.1.x to include latest security-patched version, NuGetToolInstaller not needed as already on agent, dotnet restore step also not needed as dotnet build does implicit restore.

Comment: @alv as I said the environment feature doesn't support WebApps.

Comment: whilst an environment can be tied to an exact resource (like kubernetes or a virtual machine) which give extra bells and whilstles in the azdo user interface. But an environment can also be created with neither of these specific resources connected to it at all, this would work in your case. For example I deploy to multiple service fabric environments using a 'general environment'.

Comment: @alv do you have an example for this? I can't find any documentation or example online. Thanks!

Comment: I can only point you to the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#target-an-environment-from-a-deployment-job - split your pipeline into 2 stages, a build(CI) stage and a deploy (CD) stage, and use a deployment job w/environment in the CD stage.

Comment: Thank you @alv I made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by downgrading the Azure App Service deploy task to version 3.*, that was also the difference between my YAML file and the Release pipeline I created using the GUI.

I still think it should work with the latest version, but for now I'm unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

There are many parts to this, since your solution already working in YAML and you only left with approval, this can be easily achieved using YAML as well

You can leverage the Environment feature of Azure DevOps. In the Environment section, you can add approvals as below

[image]

[image]

Select respective Environment( You can manually create the same based on your YAML )

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above one is one of the solutions. Let me know if this works. Another solution is using the Deploy method under release pipeline

In that case, you need to deploy web job and actual code separately

1. First Deploy web job under wwwroot>>app_data>>job
2. then deploy the remaining code(if deploying along with application code) to wwwroot

Once you need to manually add the web job in Azure App service post that it will directly work with deployment.
I am doing a similar way in my environment and working fine

Comment: The environment feature **doesn't support** WebApps.